# How will I get route along 3 points?

Tags: pgrouting

Can any one help me out to find route for three points. the points are start-via(Mid)-End. I want route to get create from start point to via(mid) point and via point to end point. Can any one can provide any help to me regarding this issue.
using this link:[http://workshop.pgrouting.org/index.html. How it will be done Sql query to retive same from php file in link above

Comment: You can do two separate routing operations: one start-mid and one mid-end. What exactly do you need help with?